# Como desplegar componente en un ngFor en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

¿qué tal? Bueno para empezar estoy haciendo un proyecto en Angular, en esta parte obtengo datos y los imprimo de forma típica, pero quiero abrir un componente cuando pique un botón, el problema es que cuando presiono el botón en todas mis impresiones se genera, en un ejemplo se vera más claro...!

Mis variables las imprimo así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se presiona el botón se debe abrir un componente como este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que se imprime en todos los elementos del For cuando presiono cualquier botón
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, en esa imagen le presione al botón de 'juan' pero también abrió el componente de 'sadako'

mi componente es el siguiente:

```
export class ModifyComponent implements OnInit {
  alumno : Alumno[];
  res : number;
  show : boolean = true;

  @ViewChild('err')err:ElementRef; //referencia a objeto del html
  @ViewChild('help')help:ElementRef;

  constructor(private listarService : ListarService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.obternerAlumnos();
  }

  state(){
      this.show = false;
  }

  obternerAlumnos(){
     this.listarService.obtenerAlumnos().subscribe(
        respuesta => {
          this.res = Object.keys(respuesta).length;
          if(this.res >= 1){
            this.alumno = respuesta;
          }else{
            this.err.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
          }
        });
    }
   }
```

Y mi html es el siguiente

```
 <form action="submit" class="container-fluid">
   <h2>Selecciona que estudiante quieres modificar</h2>
   <h2 class="error" style="display: none" #err>-- Sin datos :( --</h2>
   <div *ngFor="let a of alumno">
       <span class="del">
         <p>{{a.nombre}}</p>
         <button (click)="state()" type="button"><i class="material-icons">mode</i></button>
       </span>
       <div *ngIf="show; else elseBlock"></div>
       <ng-template #elseBlock><app-mod-help></app-mod-help></ng-template>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Imagino que debe ser algo de reiniciar mi variable show al final de cada llamada del for, pero no estoy nada seguro y ya estoy atorado en esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se abren todos porque están enlazados a una sola variable `show`.

Eso puede solucionarse creando una variable `show` para cada objeto.

```
if(this.res >= 1){
      this.alumno = respuesta;
      // aquí se agrega una variable a cada objeto
      this.alumno.forEach(a => a.show = false);
    }
```

Y luego en la plantilla se usa la nueva variable:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of alumno">
       <span class="del">
         <p>{{a.nombre}}</p>
         <button (click)="a.show = !a.show" type="button"><i class="material-icons">mode</i></button>
       </span>
       <div *ngIf="!a.show; else elseBlock"></div>
       <ng-template #elseBlock><app-mod-help></app-mod-help></ng-template>
   </div>
```